# Center a checkbox in a Kendo Grid Cell

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm using a template in a kendo grid to create checkbox:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: products,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        scrollable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },
                        columns: [
                          {
                        field:'<div style="text-align: center"><input id="masterCheck" class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" /><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="masterCheck"></label></div>', 
                        template: '<div style="text-align: center"><input id="${ProductName}" type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox rowSelect"/><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="${ProductName}"></label></div>',
                        headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"},
                        width: 38,
                        editable: false,
                        sortable: false // may want to make this sortable later. will need to build a custom sorter.
                      },
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
                        ]
                    });
                });
```

Here's a dojo of the code: http://dojo.telerik.com/IVopi

You'll notice the checkbox is in not centered in the grid cell. How can I center the checkbox in the grid cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the templates you can lose the DIV and just include the checkbox and label. Then use attributes and headerAttributes to give the cell and header cell class names:

```
{
    field:'<input id="masterCheck" class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" /><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="masterCheck"></label>', 
    template: '<input id="${ProductName}" type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox rowSelect"/><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="${ProductName}"></label>',
    headerAttributes:{ 
       "class": "checkbox-header-cell",
    },
    attributes: {
       "class": "checkbox-cell",
    },
    width: 38,
    editable: false,
    sortable: false // may want to make this sortable later. will need to build a custom sorter.
},
```

Now use CSS with those class names to center the checkboxes:

```
  <style>
    .checkbox-cell {
      text-align: center !important; 
      padding: 0 !important;    
    }    
    .checkbox-header-cell {      
      text-align: center !important; 
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .checkbox-header-cell .k-checkbox-label:before {
      margin-top: -12px  !important;

    }
  </style>
```

You can play around with the CSS to get exactly what you want...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the content of the cell isn't centered is that the cell itself, the `<td>` element, has padding.

You can either remove this padding by overriding the styling of the grid or by applying a negative margin value to the content of your cell template.

Replace the `text-align: center` style you entered in your template with `margin: -8px` and the checkbox will be better positioned.